# How to style ion-alert header in ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I created an alert controller and am trying to style the `header` of the alert. I have checked out the docs but i couldn't find any solution.

```
  async showAlert(header, subHeader, message) {
    const alert = await this.alertCtl.create({
      cssClass: "my-custom-class",
      header,
      subHeader,
      message,
      buttons: ["Ok"],
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

How do i style the **header** of the alert ?.

**Edit:**
This is the global.scss file

```
.my-custom-class {
  .alert-wrapper {
    .alert-head {
      color: green;
    }
  }
}
```

Have tried this as suggested by @Vijay Kumawat but it still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a custom class to the alert while creating the alert which I can see is `my-custom-class` in your alert. You can use this class as below to customize the alert style

```
.my-custom-class {
  .alert-wrapper {
    .alert-head {
        // header styling here eg. background
        h2 {
            // header text styling here eg. color, font size
        }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: the text in the header are in h2 tag so styling regarding text (font size, color etc. ) will go under h2 otherwise h2's default style will override the custom css added directly to .alert-head

NOTE: you can check the ion alert's element structure using inspect element.

Comment: have tried that, but it still now working

Comment: Where you have added this? It should be in the global.scss file

Comment: I added it in my `global.scss` file and it still the same

Comment: This should work, I have used this a lot. Can you share your styling what you added in the style and how you want it to be?

Comment: have added an edit to the post as you requested

Comment: Okay I got your issue, updated the answer now. .alert-head is a container div so probably your color is getting override by its h2 element.